# Proof that all nonreal eigenvalues of real coefficient linear transforms come in conjugate pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know how to prove what the title says using determinants, but let's say I wanted to use another approach. In Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*, he seems to avoid using determinants for proving things about determinants. He successfully proves that every linear transformation  $T$ in a complex vector space $V$ has an eigenvalue by roughly the following procedure:

Suppose $\mathbf{v}\in V$, $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$ and $n=\dim V$. Then the list $(\mathbf{v},T\mathbf{v},\dots,T^n\mathbf{v})$ is linearly dependent in $V$ since it contains $n+1$ vectors.

This means that there exist $a_0,\dots,a_n$, not all zero such that

$$a_0\mathbf{v}+a_1T\mathbf{v}+\dots+a_nT^n\mathbf{v}=0.$$

If we let $m$ be the largest index such that $a_m\neq0$, $0<m\leq n$ since the coefficients cannot all be $0$.

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, this expression can be factored into:

$$c(T-\lambda_1I)\dots(T-\lambda_mI)\mathbf{v}=0.$$

Since $\mathbf{v}\neq\mathbf{0}$, at least one of the $(T-\lambda_j)$ terms is not injective.

Could one prove the title of the question in a similar way? I think one could get a factor in the form $(T^2+\alpha T+\beta I)$, but I'm stuck with proving that exactly that factor must be injective. Ideas?

Comment: If $Av=\lambda v$ then $A\bar v=\bar\lambda\bar v$, where $\bar v$ is taking component-wise conjugates. That's only true because $A$ is real, so that $A=\bar A$, where $\bar A$ means taking component-wise conjugates of the entries of $A$.

Comment: Factoring $(T^2 + \alpha T + \beta I)$ will not help in that proof, as only one of those factors is guaranteed to be non-injective. 

@ThomasAndrews comment could be turned into an answer.